# Creating a contact form with Jquery/PHP that does not refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'm a fairly new to web development. Mostly I'm a freelance artist trying to make her own web portfolio. Although I recognize the importance of learning the basics of code so I'm trying to do this all myself as I go.
Currently I'm at a stalemate with a simple PHP/HTML Contact Form. I have some forms on my HTML index (it's a one page site) that call in my PHP file to send the message to my email. As you probably would expect it looks a little something like this:
Index.html

```
  <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="First and last name">


  <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address">


  <textarea name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>


  <input id="Submit" class="submit_btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

Contactme.php

```
 <?php $name = $_POST['name'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];

$message = $_POST['message'];
$from = 'From: mywebsite.com'; 
$to = 'twocoffeespoons@gmail.com'; 
$subject = 'Hello';

$body = "From: $name\n E-Mail: $email\n Message:\n $message";

if ($_POST['submit']) {         
    if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) { 
  echo '<script language="javascript">';
  echo 'alert("message successfully sent")';
  echo '</script>';
  } else { 
  echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and stry again!</p>'; 
  } 
}
?>
```

I think I understand the basics, but I'm really not satisfied with my form. When the user hits my submit button the php script is run and they are taken to a different page. I know I could simply change my website to index.php but I'd rather not. Even then the website still refreshes after I hit send. I've been looking through everything I can find, but the tutorials seem really outdated.
Does anybody have some advice? I'd like to use AJAX/JQuery to send the input to my php while the user just gets a "Your Message Has Been Sent Alert" without leaving my website. I'm sorry if my terminology is off or a little confusing. Like I said I'm really new to this, and have been trying to solve this problem for the last three days with no results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    var postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
        success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
        {
            //data: return data from server
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            //if fails     
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});
```

HTML CODE

```
<form id="ajaxform" action="your_url_goes_here">
    .......
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<input name="name" id="first" type="text" placeholder="First and last name">


  <input name="email" type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email address">


  <textarea id="message" name="message" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>


  <input id="Submit" class="submit_btn" name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit">
  <span class="error" style="display:none">All Fields Are Required!</span>
  <span class="success" style="display:none">Contact Form Submitted Successfully</span>
```

Script

```
$(function() {
    $(".submit_btn").click(function() {
        var name = $("#first").val();
        var email = $("#email").val();
        var message = $("#message").val();
        var dataString = 'name=' + name + '&email=' + email+ '&message' + message;

        if (name == '' || email == '' || message == '') {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
        else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Contactme.php",
                data: dataString,
                success: function() {
                    $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                    $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
                }
            });
        }
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#formid").submit(function() {
    // your code
    return false; //return false also works..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 - just try this code it will help you , submit your form as method="POST" and action="abc.php";

<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

$to=$_POST['email'];


$from=$_POST['name'];


$message=$_POST['message'];





$headers = "From:" . $from;
mail($to,$message,$headers);
echo "Mail Sent.";
}
?>
```